# Multiple image reading in a given naming method in openCV and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a series of images with names like "alpha-beta-0", "alpha-beta-1",......."alpha-beta-20".
I have to read these images and give output as one image after process them.

How can I do that in OpenCV and C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use universal `cv::VideoCapture` class that is able to load regularly named images as a video sequence (see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-open)).

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("alpha-beta-%d");
cv::Mat img;
while (cap.read(img)) {
    // process image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some codes like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 20 ; i++)
{
     std::stringstream str;
     str << "alpha-beta" << i;
     cv::Mat img = cv::imread(str.str());
     ////  process and show output ...
}
```